# spark stream and spark sql with data warehouse

Tags: apache-spark, data-warehouse

We are trying to using spark to do some real time data processing. I need do some sql-like query and analytical tasks with the real time data against historical normalized data stored in data bases. Is there anyone has done this kind of work or design? Any suggestion or material would be truly welcomed.

Comment: Could you provide more information on this. If you had your data warehouse as hive tables and your streaming job you could convert your RDD's contained in your  DStreams to dataframes and register them as tables. 
It really depends on what you are trying to do

Comment: The key problem is we trying to join two tables.One table‘s source is from spark stream and the other one is a big table stored in databases like vertical or mysql. But when the data grows, the computation would be really slow I guess.